# Uso de «tú» y «uno» como pronombres impersonales en la misma oración

Tags: gramática, pronombres, anglicismo

Se halla esta oración en el prefacio de *La Oveja de Nathán* (ed. 2013, Filipinas Heritage Library) en dos versiones: el inglés y el castellano (pág. xx y xxi):

> You are called by a superior or unknown Force in the universe, to bear your fruit before your journey's end.
>
> Te llama una Fuerza superior o desconocida en el universo, para que uno dé su fruto antes de llegar el fin de tu viaje.

En la versión inglesa se usa el [*Generic you*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you), en que se usa la 2ª persona "you" como pronombre impersonal.

1. ¿Es este uso de «tú» y «uno» tan adecuado en español como en inglés, o es anglicismo?
2. Si es adecuado, ¿se puede emplear ambos «tú» y «uno» en la misma oración?

Adición: aquí están los párrafos enteros en las dos versiones:

> Papa never finished his dictionary. I think Papa knew early in his life what his work was, and remained faithful till his last breath. In his youth, he had lost to gangrene all of his left arm after a bicycle accident, and could not consequently, under the rules then, enter the priesthood like his elder brother José. He was a man of great silences, and part of that silence must have been a deep sense of commitment to the work he was called to do. Yes, *called*, because that is the meaning of work, or what used to be called a *vocation*. **You are called by a superior or unknown Force in the universe, to bear your fruit before your journey's end.** For Papa, a man's honest toil is his highest point of honor. O, the very end of living, it still remains unfinished, it is nevertheless gloriously ended! What greater blessing might there be? At the very end, one's life shall have passed in secret cheer of spirit.
>
> Papá nunca terminó su Diccionario. Creo que Papá sabía temprano en su vida qué era su trabajo, y se quedó fiel a él hasta el último suspiro. En su juventud, se le perdió toda su brazo izquierdo a la gangrena, después de un accidente de bicicleta y por consiguiente, no podía, de acuerdo con los reglamentos de entonces, hacerse sacerdote como hizo su hermano mayor, José. Papá era un hombre de silencios profundísimos, y parte de ese silencio hubiera sido un sentido profundo de compromiso al trabajo que le habían llamado a hacer. Sí, *llamado*, porque eso es el significado del trabajo, o lo que solía llamarse *vocación*. **Te llama una Fuerza superior o desconocida en el universo, para que uno dé su fruto antes de llegar el final de tu viaje.** Para mi papá, el trabajo honrado de un hombre es la cúspide del honor. ¡Oh, no simplemente el trabajo, sino el trabajo de toda la vida, la cual lleva la jornada a su plenitud, para que, si al mismo final de su vida, aún queda sin acabar, ¡esté sin embargo gloriosamente acabado! ¿Qué bendición más grande habría? —al final de todo, la vida de uno habrá pasado secretamente alegre en el espíritu.

Comment: Quién es el autor de la traducción al castellano?

Comment: Ambas versiones dicen que su autor es [Gémino Abad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9mino_Abad), hijo del autor de la novela. No es conocido si él mismo escribió la versión castellana o está traducida por alguien.

Comment: Pues esa frase sola está muy mal traducida, el "uno" no tiene sentido. No sé si en contexto es diferente.

Comment: Es un error de traducción. Tiene que ser "para que tu fruto venga a luz antes del fin de tu viaje. No tiene nada que ver con el inglés.  [you nunca es impersonal] O algo parecido.

Comment: Creo que debería incluir el párrafo entero para dar contexto, esa oración sola es un descalabro.

Comment: En inglés, existe un "you" impersonal: https://www.nativespeakeronline.com/ielts-speaking-tips/the-impersonal-you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para hacer referencia genérica, se puede usar tanto "tú" (2a persona del singular) como "uno" (3a persona del singular), pero no es correcto mezclarlos, mucho menos en una oración o un texto corto. Por lo tanto, la oración en cuestión debiera ser:

- **Te** llama una Fuerza superior o desconocida del universo para que **des tu** fruto antes de que llegue el fin de **tu** viaje.

o

- **A uno** lo llama una Fuerza superior o desconocida del universo para que **dé su** fruto antes de que llegue el fin de **su** viaje.

También podría usarse la primera persona del plural con el mismo sentido genérico:

- **Nos** llama una Fuerza superior o desconocida del universo para que **demos nuestro** fruto antes de que llegue el fin de **nuestro** viaje.

Luego de leer la otra respuesta, debo decir que mi recomendación de no mezclar "tú" y "uno" responde a una cuestión de estilo que me parece importante preservar en una oración como la citada, que está bastante lejos de ser coloquial. No obstante, en el habla coloquial pueden en efecto mezclarse ambas formas, aunque esto no sea aconsejable en la norma más culta. En [este artículo](https://www.redalyc.org/pdf/602/60248205.pdf) que puede encontrarse en Internet leemos:

> MEZCLA DE UNAS Y OTRAS PERSONAS GENERALES
>
> Fernández Ramírez alude a “la mezcla de unas y otras personas generales”
> como “prueba de la indiferencia con que se emplean algunas
> veces”15. Casos de tal mezcla de “tú” y “uno” y aun de “tú”, “uno”, “se”
> impersonal, y “hay que” abundan en la base de datos, como se ve en
> estos ejemplos:
>
> Tú convives con profesionales de otra índole, no solamente de tu carrera,
> como cuando uno está en la escuela (SNT-1, p. 21).
>
> Tú no encuentras policía de ninguna clase. Entonces, pues, uno tampoco
> entiende, ¿no?, cómo es esto (BOG-25, p. 339).
>
> La ropa de confección es buena. Es decir, uno se viste en cualquier sastrería de esas que comprás un traje hecho y es un traje bueno. Se viste
> bien (BA-3, p. 61).
>
> Eso lo desagrada a uno enormemente. Ese hecho de que a ti te hablen, y
> que tú no entiendas (CAR-4, p. 55)16.

Answer (score -1):

**Te llama una Fuerza superior o desconocida en el universo, para que uno dé su fruto antes de llegar el fin de tu viaje.**

Desde mi punto de vista;

- 1. El uso de "tú" y "uno," como "tu genérico o impersonal español" es adecuado (el uso de "tú" con el sentido de "uno").
- 2. En este caso se pueden emplear ambos, "tu" y "uno", pues se mantiene la concordancia, ya que esta refiriéndose a sí mismo cuando utiliza uno u otro.

El uso de este "tu genérico o impersonal español" se encuentra más extendido en unas zonas que en otras.

---

En este caso "**uno**" no se considera anglicismo, pues los usos superfluos del indefinido debidos al influjo de aquel idioma están enfocados principalmente cuando "uno", "un", "una" hacen la función de artículo tradicional indeterminado o indefinido, esta influencia inglesa se aprecia cuando por ejemplo se dice, "Soy un doctor", cuando lo correcto seria decir "Soy doctor".

Aunque se entendería perfectamente, otra traducción o construcción de la frase;

> Eres llamado por una Fuerza superior o desconocida en el universo,
> para dar tu fruto antes del final de tu viaje.

Sin embargo, la frase que aparece en español esta bien sustentada.

> Te llama una Fuerza superior o desconocida en el universo, para que
> **uno** dé su fruto antes de llegar el fin de tu viaje.

En este caso el pronombre indefinido "**uno**" funciona como reflexivo en oraciones impersonales, "**uno mismo**", por tanto es totalmente válido y normal.

**"Te tomas unos vinos, y a uno le da por decir tonterías, aunque no seas consciente de ello."**

**" (Tú o Uno Impersonal)Te toma/s unos vinos, y a (ti o a uno) uno le da por decir tonterías, aunque (tu o uno) no sea/s consciente de ello."**

- **" "Uno" se toma unos vinos, y a "uno" le da por decir tonterías, aunque "uno" no sea consciente de ello."**
- **""Te" tomas unos vinos, y "te" da por decir tonterías, aunque "tu" no seas consciente de ello."**

Como se ve el uso reiterado del " te (tu) y uno" es excesivo para la frase y resulta redundante.

El uso del ("**tu**") y el ("**uno**") de forma alternante, da como resultado una redacción más fluida y menos lineal.

El pronombre "**te**" y el pronombre "**uno**" se pueden utilizar indirectamente para referirse e incluir al yo que habla.

---

El autor comienza utilizando el "**Te**" o "tu" genérico impersonal con el sentido de "**uno**" para referirse a una persona genérica, es decir, a una persona cualquiera generaliza, incluido el mismo autor, esa "llamada de la Fuerza Superior" donde "**todos**", incluido el propio escritor, siente esa "llamada", para dar su (mejor) "fruto" (acciones, hechos del autor), y posteriormente, en segundo término, aunque parece dirigirse al lector para anunciarle el ocaso al que todos llegamos, (la muerte), en realidad lo que esta haciendo es utilizar de nuevo el "tu" genérico, para "**hablar de su propio viaje**", cuando dice, "**el fin de tu viaje**", se esta refiriendo a sí mismo, a su persona (a su viaje), no se está refiriendo al viaje de otro. Es el "viaje de uno mismo". Por lo tanto la concordancia esta magistralmente construida.

**P.D.1** En este pequeño párrafo se intuye, por las características y giros descritos, que el autor conocía perfectamente la lengua y que escribiría la obra originalmente en español, para después, ser traducida al inglés.

---

**P.D.2**

Después de investigar un poco sobre la obra y su autor.

**La Oveja de Nathán**, fue escrita por **Antonio M. Abad**, autor filipino en lengua española , comenzada en Noviembre de 1925 y terminada en Marzo de 1926, en Cebú (Filipinas).

**Antonio Abad y Mercado** (Barili, Cebú, 10 de Mayo de 1894 - 10 de abril de 1970) *fue un prolífico escritor y profesor filipino de lengua española, galardonado con el Premio Zóbel​ y gran defensor de la lengua española en su país. Es padre del también escritor Germino Abad (nacido el 5 de Febrero de 1939), aunque este usa el inglés como lengua literaria y no domina el castellano.*

Por tanto, siendo escritor, profesor de lengua española y galardonado con premios de gran prestigio, me es difícil considerar, como se ha dicho por aquí, que la oración no es correcta o que se trata de una mala traducción, ya que desde mi punto de vista y con todos mis respetos, aunque es una construcción menos habitual también es posible utilizarla, pues habla de sí mismo de forma genérica en toda la frase utilizando el "tu genérico o impersonal español" (el uso de "tú" con el sentido de "uno").

Tampoco el autor de la obra puede ser "Gémino Abad", hijo de Antonio Abad, pues la novela la termino el padre en 1926 y el hijo nació en 1939.

Comment: No creo sea necesario adjuntar ningún currículum para intentar dar validez a una respuesta. Afortunadamente este es un sitio que aún mantiene un amplio margen de libertad en cuanto a las aportaciones y la mayoría de los que participamos lo hacemos por el simple hecho de intercambiar conocimientos.

Comment: @Danielillo el "curriculum" (escritor, profesor de la lengua española) no es de Diego, sino del autor de la obra (Antonio Abad y Mercado). El argumento que se da en esta respuesta es que si el autor de la obra tiene esos credenciales, su uso de "tú" y "uno" podría ser correcto. Que no tiene por qué ser cierto, pero es un argumento que de puede dar.

Comment: Objetivamente no creo que la observación merezca un negativo, cuando lo único que se pretende es aportar documentación suficiente para mejorar las contestaciones. La respuesta a la pregunta se encuentra en el cuerpo de la misma y no al final. PD2 es solo una nota que solo aporta información sobre la obra y su autor, y que intenta, siempre desde el respeto, dar a los que han dicho que es una mala traducción, un error o que la oración no es correcta, alguna otra motivación para seguir buscando una respuesta mejor, pues PS2 no es argumento de validez de nada. Solo sirve para conocer a su autor.